# Определить количество пятизначных чисел в девятеричной системе счисления

Tags: python

Определите количество пятизначных чисел, записанных в девятеричной системе счисления, которые не начинаются с нечётных цифр, не оканчиваются цифрами 1 или 8, а также содержат в своей записи не более одной цифры 3. Правильный ответ: 18944

Не могу найти ошибку в своем коде:

```
import itertools

l = list(itertools.product('012345678', repeat=5))
fin = []

for i in l:
    if (i[0] in '02468') and (i[-1] not in '18') and (i.count('3') <= 1):
        fin.append(i)

print(len(fin))
```

Comment: Числа не начинаются с `0`

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А ведь можно и по формуле посчитать: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##lY/BbsMgEETvfMUouWA3tpTQVG6l/kd6pAHXSHixDG6Sr3fApq1UqYdy4DC7M/tmuIXOkZhnwiuemY3/kbFhNBQ4A6wmvjk8PjWbAlu0ZvQBynyYEGcleNRo6t/16HExMWjKUwgYQug0eqOU1avqoyk9TtW@KEtuq0NM3eJU1/UbqrwEGRAFmBad/NQg953W54AyRSQvrPwCeoG@nu2kNPaQpNDsIK11F4jF9PAL9X@cIt3yiUbCWxfQunH1JlLXrhV@6NZmOHfOawzOB@No8ciMkzuIPzvs0Cw10nrBinm@Aw)

```
n = 9
l = 5

print(
  len("2468") # first digit
  * ( # numbers without digit 3 in the middle digits
      (n-1)**(l-2) ## X...Y - digits at ... if have no 3 in them
      * (n-2) # last digit: exclude 1 and 8, allow 3
    + # numbers with digit 3 in the middle digits
      (n-1)**(l-3) # save a slot for 3 in ... of X...Y
      * (l-2) # chose postion for a 3
      * (n-3) # last digit: exclude 1, 8 and 3
  )
)
```

Если убрать комментарии, то останется так: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0/BVsGSKwdImnJxFRRl5pVo5KTmaSgZmZhZKGkqaCloaOTpGmpqaWnk6BqB@XkgWlsBIWwMFkZIG2tqav7/DwA)

```
n = 9
l = 5

print(len("2468") * ((n-1)**(l-2) * (n-2) + (n-1)**(l-3) * (l-2) * (n-3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто убрать в проверке первого числа ноль, число не может начинаться с нуля.

```
import itertools

l = list(itertools.product('012345678', repeat=5))
fin = []

for i in l:
    if (i[0] in '2468') and (i[-1] not in '18') and (i.count('3') <= 1):
        fin.append(i)

print(len(fin)
```

Comment: Жаль, что с двадцатизначными числами такое не очень подходит